# cURL sending variables not working

Tags: curl

I am trying to use cURL to send post data to a specific file but doesn't seem to work. Do I have a syntax error or am I closing curl too early?
Is there  good way to test it and see what variables I am sending.

```
$my_url = 'http://www.website.com/file.php';
              $post_vars = 'custom_id1=' .$cid. '&custom_id2=' .$cid2. '&invoice_id=' .$invoiceid. '&amount=' .$amount;

              $curl = curl_init($my_url);
              curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
              curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_vars);
              curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
              curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
              curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

              $response = curl_exec($curl);

              curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cURL syntax error
Try this

```
<?php
$my_url = 'http://www.website.com/file.php';
$post_vars = 'custom_id1=' .$cid. '&custom_id2=' .$cid2. '&invoice_id=' .$invoiceid. '&amount=' .$amount;
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $my_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_vars);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
?>
```